# How much should brick "give" when pushing against it?

Tags: brick, exterior

My wife and I are having a home built by a local contractor.  The house is wood framed construction with a brick exterior.  The home is nearly complete -- just interior trim and paint work remains.

When I pushed against the exterior brick, I could hear the trim on the eaves flexing.  Should the brick give at all?  Also does Alabama have any building requirements addressing this?  I'm not sure if they used brick ties or if they are even required since the walls aren't load bearing.

Comment: I'm not a mason, but I'm nearly certain that bricks shouldn't give at all. Are you sure it's actual brick with mortar (vs a brick cladding product that is installed more like siding)?

Comment: @DA01: It's definitely brick with mortar.  I saw them putting it up -- just didn't look to see if they used ties.

Comment: Ties in and of themselves aren't going to make a wall give or not give. They do help keep a facade from leaning over time. But if your wall 'gives' then there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Good luck. Keep us posted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not at all.  If it's real brick.

If it's a veneer, that's different.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll make sure to bring it up during the home inspection.  Any idea if this would be addressed in building codes? If so, what would it be called?

Comment: I would bring it up *now*.

Comment: I'm calling my agent tonight.  Thanks everyone for your help.